# How am I supposed to initialize a array using calloc inside a function?

Tags: c, malloc, calloc

While trying to solve a problem called spiral matrix, I encountered a problem that i was not able to initialize a array inside of a function using calloc.

```
/*
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */
int* spiralOrder(int** matrix, int matrixSize, int* matrixColSize, int* returnSize){
    *returnSize = matrixSize * matrixColSize[0];
    int list[] = calloc(0, (*returnSize)*sizeof(int));
    return list;

}
```

While trying to compile I am getting this exception Can someone explain why is this happening

```
solution.c: In function ‘spiralOrder’
Line 6: Char 18: error: invalid initializer [solution.c]
     int list[] = calloc(0, (*returnSize)*sizeof(int));
                  ^~~~~~
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays require an initializer list to initialize them.  But you don't actually want an array in this case, as returning a pointer to local memory will be invalid once the function returns.

You want to assign the return value of `calloc` to a pointer and return that pointer.  Also, you're calling `calloc` incorrectly.  The first parameter is the number of elements and the second is the size of each element.

```
int *list = calloc(*returnSize, sizeof *list);
return list;
```

Comment: why are you using *sizeof(int)?

Comment: `s/*sizeof(int)/sizeof *list`

Comment: @HarshitSingh matrix is supposed to store ints and calloc allocates chars, so you need to allocate *returnSize elements each of size the size of an int.